# Get file path stored to string var with SaveFileDialog C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating an installer and i would like to know how to use SaveFileDialog to get the file path where the user wants to install their mod to. The user should be able to click a button to open up the dialog, navigate to the folder and click select folder and once done is clicked have it stored as {DownloadPath}.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/windows/how-to-open-common-system-dialog-box?view=netdesktop-6.0)

There is also [a tutorial](https://wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-openfiledialog/) on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var filePath = string.Empty;

    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        Filter = @"Exe Files (.exe)|*.exe|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    };

    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (saveFileDialog.FileName != string.Empty)
    {
        filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
    }
```